# Compare adjacent values in Unix array

Tags: arrays, shell, unix

I have an array like `a=( 1 3 2 34 5)`

I want to compare values adjacent to each other (compare 1 with 3, 3 with 2, 2 with 34, and so on).

Print message 1 if they are same, or message 2 if they are not.

```
a=( 1 1 2 34 5)
len=${#a[@]}
for  i in `seq 0 $len`
do
if [ ${a[i]} -eq ${a[i+1]} ]; then

echo "values are same"
else
echo "values are different"
fi
```

done

After comparing values 34 and 5 , throwing error.

```
+ '[' 34 -eq 5 ']'
+ echo 'values are different'
 values are different
+ for i in '`seq 0 $len`'
 + '[' 5 -eq ']'
 b.sh: line 27: [: 5: unary operator expected
+ echo 'values are different'
```

-Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  We're happy to help around here, but we're not a code writing service.  Show us some snippets of what you've tried so far and we'll help you figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Can you also show example inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is expected. You are going beyond the array size. Your loop uses length of the array which is 5 and you continue to compare the last element to the next which does not exist. You should stop comparing less than the size. Consider the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(1 1 2 34 5)

for ((index=0; index < ${#array[@]} - 1; index++)); do
    echo "--> ${array[index]} | ${array[index + 1]} <--"
    if [[ ${array[index]} -eq ${array[index + 1]} ]]; then
        echo "values are same"
    else
        echo "values are different"
    fi
done
```

**Output:**

```
--> 1 | 1 <--
values are same
--> 1 | 2 <--
values are different
--> 2 | 34 <--
values are different
--> 34 | 5 <--
values are different
```

There are a couple of improvements over your script. Use of `[[` instead of `[`. avoiding unnecessary use of `seq` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Debian's **num-utils** package contains the util `numinterval`, which compares adjacent values from *STDIN*.  Here's some code:

```
printf "%s\n" ${a[*]}  | numinterval | sed -n 's/0/same/p;t;s/.*/different/p'
```

How it works:  `printf` each value in array `${a[*]}` on separate lines, pipe to `numinterval`, then `sed` which prints "*same*" if the number is a "*0*", or "*different*" if not.

Output:

```
same
different
different
different
```

The same code can be scavenged to produce a quickie comparison chart, (read it like a triangle, long side on left):

```
paste <(printf "%s\n" ${a[*]}) \
      <(printf "%s\n" ${a[*]} | numinterval) \
      <(printf "%s\n" ${a[*]} | numinterval | 
        sed -n 's/0/same/p;t;s/.*/different/p')
```

...which outputs:

```
1   0   same
1   1   different
2   32  different
34  -29 different
5
```